# Implement micro batching in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm developing a kafka based application in which kafka listener will listen for record;Once kafka receive a record I can need to write the record into a file.
Here to write the record into a file we want to use microbatching with batchsize and timeout settings.
For example batchsize is 10 and timeout setting is 1000 ms , that means wait for 10 records before write into file with 1000 ms waittime.If in any case Kafka received only 5 records in 1000 ms then write only 5 records in that batch.

How efficiently I can do that in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common approaches in this case is to put all your records in a queue. And have one thread wich will take this records when your queue reaches size of 10 or after 1000ms, depending on what comes first.

Consumer code:

```
 CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(10);
 countDownLatch.await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 int queueSize = queue.size();
 for(int i = 0; i < queueSize; ++i) {
     ... do your work here or put in a batch a do it right after loop
 }
```

Producer code:

```
 Record record = ...receive new record...
 queue.put(record);
 consumer.getCountDownLatch().countDown();
```

As a queue I recommend using unbound one, like `LinkedTransferQueue`, because you don't want to stop your producer when you reached 10 tasks, you still need to consume results from kafka.

Also another option is [reactive streams](http://www.baeldung.com/java-9-reactive-streams).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using the [Kafka Connect API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html). This is [part of Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectapi), and is designed to support the kind of process you describe.

There is a [developer guide here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html).